# Unknown type "" in grapthqls files with GraphQL in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, graphql

I have created multiple graphqls files with multiple types but the Intellij will not recognize the types when used.

!Important: No error was thrown at compile time and the queries works as expected but visually is very annoing to have everything in red

In the next image you can see that i have the DataPage type declared but not seen by Intellij. Also the AccountFilter is from another graphqls file. As I mentioned everything work as expected.

[image]

I'm using the GraphQL plugin -> version: 4.0.2
Intellij version -> 2023.2

What can I configure in order to have the types correctly visualized in Intellij?

I have invalidate cache for intellij and tried to configure inspection regarding unresolved reference but i want to have the features provided when a real unresolved reference occure.

Comment: Also, the same unknown type is present when I try to use any imported scalar.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in WebStorm 2023.2.3. Please submit a new issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and provide a sample project where it can be reproduced.

Comment: Managed to fix-it by removing the grapghqls config file. It seems that using the default setting will not cause any issues. I guess that the config file was somehow misconfigured.